# Why are there two different duplicate post notices?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, post-notices

Why are there two different post notices applied to duplicate questions? One has an edit link, and one doesn't. Which one is applied to which questions?

This notice:

> ### marked as duplicate by OneUser, TwoUsers, ThreeUsers, FourUsers, FiveUsers
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If these answers do not address your question, please [ask a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

vs. this one:

> ### marked as duplicate by OneUser, TwoUsers, ThreeUsers, FourUsers, FiveUsers
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If these answers do not address your question, please [edit this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/199838/edit) to explain how it is different or [ask a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I think one is "On hold" which is semantically different from "Closed".

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I've seen the second one even after the 5 days...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comment, the second post notice only appears for the original poster of the question. Other users only see the first notice. In the past, only the first one would appear to all users.